How do I call a C# method with optional arguments from F#?
I'm developing a Discord bot in F# and trying to use the Discord.Net library. While following the guide on slash commands, I tried to copy this example from C# to F#:
var guildCommand = new Discord.SlashCommandBuilder()
        .WithName("list-roles")
        .WithDescription("Lists all roles of a user.")
        .AddOption("user", ApplicationCommandOptionType.User, "The users whos roles you want to be listed", isRequired: true);

Copying the code, I get this:
#r "nuget: Discord.Net,3.15.0"

open Discord

let testCommandBuilder =
    (new SlashCommandBuilder())
        .WithName("list-roles")
        .WithDescription("Lists all roles of a user.")
        .AddOption(
            "user",
            ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            "The users whos roles you want to be listed",
            isRequired = true
        )

I get no errors (usually red squiggly lines) in my editor for this code. However, when I run this snippet using dotnet fsi (Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.8.102.0 for F# 8.0), I get this error:
error FS0505: The member or object constructor 'AddOption' does not take 3 argument(s). An overload was found taking 1 arguments.

Checking the documentation for AddOption, I see that that the method takes 3 required parameters (name, type, and description) while the rest either have default values or are optional. The source code shows this as well. The VSCode F# extension seems to confirm this, as I see the following when typing the parameters:

Upon more experimenting, I found that if I included all the parameters with default values in C#, the code compiles:
#r "nuget: Discord.Net,3.15.0"

open Discord

let testCommandBuilder =
    (new SlashCommandBuilder())
        .WithName("list-roles")
        .WithDescription("Lists all roles of a user.")
        .AddOption(
            "user",
            ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            "The users whos roles you want to be listed",
            isAutocomplete = false,
            options = ([] |> ResizeArray<SlashCommandOptionBuilder>),
            channelTypes = ([] |> ResizeArray<ChannelType>),
            nameLocalizations = Map.empty,
            descriptionLocalizations = Map.empty,
            choices = [||]
        )

However, I'm not sure why this is necessary if the parameters show up as optional in the parameters. Likewise, if I try to construct an equivalent F# example, I don't need to specify values for the default parameters explicitly:
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Example() =
    member this.Function(x: string, y: int, z: string, [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue(5)>] a: int, ?b: bool) = a

let x = (new Example()).Function(x = "hi", y = 0, z = "hi")

printfn "%d" x // prints 5

How do I call the AddOption function without specifying values for all the optional parameters with default values?
EDIT:
To test this further, I created a Github Repository with a simple fsproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Discord.Net" Version="3.15.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

and the exact same code as the first F# snippet in Program.fs, with the #r directive removed. I set up Github Actions to run this with the following workflow:
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_204:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.204'
      - name: Version setup / checks
        run: |
          dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 8.0.204 --force
          dotnet --version
      - run: |
          dotnet run
  build_300:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.300'
      - name: Version setup / checks
        run: |
          dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 8.0.300 --force
          dotnet --version
      - run: |
          dotnet run

For versions up to and including .NET SDK 8.0.204, the build fails. For versions of .NET SDK 8.0.300 and higher, the build succeeds. What change was originally causing this issue?


my guess is that there is/was an extension method in play and/or there is a formatting issue, and that the namespace might not have been opened when you tried first? Optional C# args with default values are supported and handled fine in general. Maybe separate the code out to remove formatting and/or parens from the equation?

Your first F# code snippet builds and runs fine for me, so I suspect the error message you're seeing is coming from somewhere else.

@RubenBartelink Even if I separate the AddOption to a separate binding, I get the same error. Removing that specific method call allows the method to compile for me. Unless there is some other way I can separate the code?

@BrianBerns I've edited my original snippet so that it can be run directly from an fsx file (with dependencies loaded using #r) and the version of F# Interactive under which I ran the code. I am still getting the same error. Could you specify the versions under which you successfully ran the code?

@RubenBartelink I've also linked to the source code and this doesn't seem like an extension method to me (within the Discord namespace and SlashCommandBuilder class).

Here's the output from F# interactive.

@BrianBerns I took that snippet and tried running it directly in interactive like you did and got this output. Unless I'm missing something, the only difference I see in our outputs is the versions. Did something change in how this code is run between 12.8.102.0 and 12.8.300.0?

That is strange. Can you try compiling your code in a .fsproj instead of running F# interactive?

@BrianBerns The original code was run in the context of an fsproj, though I can try isolating it to a separate example. FWIW, I tried upgrading various versions and can confirm that the snippet compiles and works with .NET SDK 8.0.300. Using .NET SDK 8.0.204 and prior, the compilation error occurs. Did I stumble on a compiler bug?

@BrianBerns since you asked for an fsproj, I went a little further and created a github repo for both the failing version and the working version in Github Actions side by side (the original question has been edited to add more detail). This might aid in investigating further.

I cloned your repository locally, installed .NET 8.0.204, created a matching global.json, and the project still builds and runs for me without any issues.

@BrianBerns I'm not sure how this could be the case; within the Github repo I print the version before running dotnet run in the CI action and the issue only appears for jobs with 8.0.204 or earlier. I'm unsure how I could further reproduce this, as the Github action isn't running on my computer. Could you confirm that the version is actually set to 8.0.204 (especially given the global.json matching rules)? Otherwise, maybe this is something platform specific?

I was finally able to reproduce this on another machine with a slightly older version of Visual Studio (17.9.6). Will investigate the difference.

OK, I think I know why this is failing to compile for you. The problem is the choices parameter array at the end of the C# method's signature:
public SlashCommandBuilder AddOption(string name, ApplicationCommandOptionType type,
    string description, bool? isRequired = null, bool? isDefault = null, bool isAutocomplete = false, double? minValue = null, double? maxValue = null,
    List<SlashCommandOptionBuilder> options = null, List<ChannelType> channelTypes = null, IDictionary<string, string> nameLocalizations = null,
    IDictionary<string, string> descriptionLocalizations = null,
    int? minLength = null, int? maxLength = null, params ApplicationCommandOptionChoiceProperties[] choices)

Calling a C# method that contains both a parameter with a default value and a parameter array is not well supported from F# (at least until recently). You can see open issues about this here and here. One easy workaround is to pass an explicit value for the parameter array:
let testCommandBuilder =
    (new SlashCommandBuilder())
        .WithName("list-roles")
        .WithDescription("Lists all roles of a user.")
        .AddOption(
            "user",
            ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            "The users whos roles you want to be listed",
            isRequired = true,
            choices = Array.empty
        )

It looks like this limitation was lifted in the latest version of the F# compiler (fsc --version = 12.8.300.0), although I didn't see it described in any release notes and the issues I referenced above are still open. (The version of .NET 8 installed is irrelevant, I think. It looks like the difference is actually in the F# compiler, which is part of the SDK. This may explain why your builds above show different behavior, although I don't know much about how GitHub actions work.)

Oh good catch, that's something I didn't even notice! Googling further, I found this issue from 2022 that was recently addressed in a pull request from February. The release notes mentioning this change are here around halfway through the list. It might be worth mentioning/quoting these in the answer for completeness.
